# how to set a width to an Telerik Angular label

Tags: css, angular, sass, telerik

I started to use Telerik in a angular component but I don't know how to set the label with.

suppose I have a component "numeric-box" and in `numeric-box.scss` I put

```
<div class="field">
    <kendo-label [text]="label">
        <kendo-numerictextbox [value]="value"></kendo-numerictextbox>
    </kendo-label>
    <span class="field-unit">{{unit}}</span>
</div>
```

in the `numeric-box.scss` i put:
`kendo-label {width = 150px}`

however this does not change the width of the label inside numeric box.

Also, just putting `label {width = 150px}` does not work as well because the scss aplies only to the component `numeric-box`, not also on the `kendo-label`. However the `label {width = 150px}` works only in main `styles.scss`

Comment: use "display: inline-block;"

Comment: @AmanSharma on what?

Comment: on label! with the width

Comment: the "label" is inside the "kendo-label" component and has any effect on children components from numeric-box